# Obfuscation (or other intelectual rights protection) for Assemblys (DLLs) compatible with Framework 4

Tags: dll, assemblies, c#-4.0, obfuscation

I need an application for obfuscation (or other intelectual rights protection) of Assemblys (DLLs) compatible with the new Framework 4.

It should be free, and not require extensive changes in my application code.

Any recomendations?

PS: I know a bunch of others for framework3.5 and before, cant find one for Framework 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a free obfuscator that works with .NET 4.0 you can use the latest version of Dotfuscator Community Edition that is available in the Beta release of Visual Studio 2010 .  The Community Edition only provides renaming but it is free.  Dotfuscator CE is installed as part of the default installation of Visual Studio 2010 and a shortcut is available on the VS2010 Tools menu.

If you want stronger obfuscation, the commercial edition of Dotfuscator has supported .NET 4 assemblies since the first public release of Visual Studio 2010 / .NET 4.0 (the October 2008 CTP version).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I unchecked it during installation, and completely forgot about it, thanks =)

It is not very good I beleave, it its a start =)

Answer (score 1):

> PS: I know a bunch of others for
>   framework3.5 and before, cant find one
>   for Framework 4.

The fact that .NET 4.0 has not been released yet might have something to do with that.

Comment: Yeah, but, if you can use it, and there is people using it, there could be already an application compatible with it, even if beta.

Comment: You can't release software with it yet. Have you tried the existing tools running against .NET 4.0?

Comment: I didnt try them all, but the ones I tryed always return an error exactly the same as if I try to build my application using framework 3.5 while importing assemblies that are build using framework 4.0.

Comment: You can't release any .NET 4.0 software yet as Microsoft has only released it as a beta (i.e. Beta 1).  Rumor has it that the Beta 2 release will have a Go-Live license which will allow for production use of .NET 4.0 Beta 2.